# Classic Vnet - Unable to SSH

Tags: azure

I have created a vnet in classic mode. I have created a classic vm and added to the vnet. I am not able to connect to the VM through SSH. No ports are accessible through telnet. Getting a connection timed out error.

I do not have any NSG or ACL. Currently there is only one VM in this vnet.

How can I enable connectivity to this VM? I do not have load balancer either.

I am trying to add my VMs to a vnet to be able to enable server-to-server communication, not for load balancing.

Comment: 1) this should be on serverfault. 2) this type of question has been asked numerous times . 3)  have you confirmed you set up an endpoint for the outside world to access? Have you tried ssh'ing via another machine on your vnet?

Answer (score 0):

I have just created ARM VMs with the same setup, and it works without any issue. Decided to stop using classic.